# Anything I do with apt runs "setting up razercfg"

Tags: apt

I tried to install razercfg using `sudo apt install razercfg`, it didn't work, error produced is:

```
    sudo apt install razercfg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
razercfg is already the newest version (0.41+ds-1build1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-42 linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic python3-click python3-colorama
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up razercfg (0.41+ds-1build1) ...
A dependency job for razerd.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript razerd, action "start" failed.
● razerd.service - Razer device state daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/razerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Sep 07 20:11:54 Hamotron systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Razer device state daemon.
Sep 07 20:11:54 Hamotron systemd[1]: razerd.service: Job razerd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 07 20:18:11 Hamotron systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Razer device state daemon.
Sep 07 20:18:11 Hamotron systemd[1]: razerd.service: Job razerd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 07 20:20:31 Hamotron systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Razer device state daemon.
Sep 07 20:20:31 Hamotron systemd[1]: razerd.service: Job razerd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dpkg: error processing package razercfg (--configure):
 installed razercfg package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qrazercfg:
 qrazercfg depends on razercfg; however:
  Package razercfg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qrazercfg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qrazercfg-applet:
 qrazercfg-applet depends on razercfg; however:
  Package razercfg is not configured yet.
 qrazercfg-applet depends on qrazercfg; however:
  Package qrazercfg is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qrazercfg-applet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous
 failure.
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 razercfg
 qrazercfg
 qrazercfg-applet
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I gave up on it and tried to install other packages, but everytime I use apt, it will say "setting up razercfg" and produce the same error. This happened on:

```
sudo apt remove polychromatic
sudo apt install python3-distutils
```

and more.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have left `razercfg` in a non-working state (installed,  not configured). The other two packages depend on a working `razercfg`. This makes the packaging system unhappy/inconsistent, so it tries to configure `razercfg` every time you invoke it, and fails, leaving `razercfg` installed, not configured.

Manual intervention is necessary. There are two different ways to resolve the problem: configure `razercfg` correctly. OR remove `razercfg`.

Reconfigure:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure razercfg qrazercfg qrazercfg.applet
```

OR

Remove from system:

```
sudo apt purge razercfg qrazercfg qrazercfg.applet
```